# Beanshell Script throws error while running from terminal but it runs perfectly in GUI mode in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I tried to run the following script:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; // necessary import
int lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("${testPlanFileDir}/csv/test_smtp_save.csv")).size() - 1; // get lines count
vars.put("lines", String.valueOf(lines)); // store the count into "lines" variable
```

To get the number of lines in my csv, so that I can execute a loop according to the number of lines in the CSV file.

The script above runs perfectly if I run from GUI mode, but when I run from terminal then it throws following error.

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval
Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
``import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; // necessary import int lines = FileUtil . . . ''
: Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation FileUtils.readLines
```

Comment: I tried your code, it runs OK on JMeter 2.13.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get this `${testPlanFileDir}` variable value? Apart from it the code looks good.

If you want to have more relevant error message you can try putting your code into the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

try {
    int lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("${testPlanFileDir}/csv/test_smtp_save.csv")).size() - 1;
    vars.put("lines", String.valueOf(lines));
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

And look into *jmeter.log* file - it will contain the "usual" stacktrace.

Alternatively you can add [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the very beginning of your Beanshell script - it will toggle debugging output to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more Beanshell-related tips and tricks

Comment: i get testPlanFileDir from following beanshell code:
    import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

    String testPlanFile = GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();

    String testPlanFileDir =    FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(testPlanFile);

vars.put("testPlanFileDir", testPlanFileDir);
log.info("testPlanFileDir:" + testPlanFileDir);

Comment: My expectation is that if you run your test in non-GUI mode - the `GuiPackage` is null, so reconsider the way you get JMeter working folder to i.e. `FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();`

Answer (score 0):

Replace ${testPlanFileDir} by:

> vars.get("testPlanFileDir")

You should avoid using Beanshell in favor of JSR223+Groovy+Cache which is embedded in JMeter 3.0, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html
- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Comment: testPlanFileDir is a variable. how can i use vars.get?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get the current directory of .jmx file.
Declared varaible TestPlanFileDir as;

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}
```